# Adding additional unmapped field within a Symfony form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I already added several things to [FileType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html) fields, like for example displaying information about the allowed file size and a preview image if appropriate.

Now, what I want to achieve is that for non-mandatory file fields there is also an additional (unmapped) checkbox shown for allowing the user to delete an existing file.

First I tried a [form typ extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) for this. Now I use a dedicated form type class. However, I couldn't cope with it yet.

Here is what I am currently doing:

1. The custom file type:

   ```
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           $fieldName = $builder->getForm()->getConfig()->getName();

           $builder->add($fieldName, 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType', $options);

           if ($options['required']) {
               return;
           }

           $builder->add($fieldName . 'DeleteFile', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType', [
               'mapped' => false,
               'label' => 'Delete existing file',
               'required' => false,
               'attr' => [
                   'title' => 'Delete this file ?'
               ]
           ]);
       }
   ```
2. The template:

   ```
   {% block my_field_upload_widget %}
     {% spaceless %}

     {# the file input field #}
     {{ block('file_widget') }}

     {% if file_path|default and not required %}
         {# the additional checkbox #}
         {{ form_row(attribute(form, id ~ 'DeleteFile')) }}
     {% endif %}

     {% endspaceless %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```

At the moment there is no input field shown at all (neither the file field nor the checkbox).

Any idea about a better approach or pointers for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by replacing

```
{{ block('file_widget') }}
```

by

```
<input type="file" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
```